# Netty 5 messageReceived not being called

Tags: java, netty

I just started using Netty. It looks very interesting but I encountered a problem. After the client is connected, a message should be received but that's not happening. For some reason connection works fine; it says `Channel Connected`.

Server:

```
    this.bossgroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap()
            .group(bossgroup)
            .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
            .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {

                @Override
                protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                    ch.pipeline().addLast("framer", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()))
                            .addLast("decoder", new StringDecoder())
                            .addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder())
                            .addLast("timer", new ReadTimeoutHandler(10))
                            .addLast("handler", new ChannelHandler());
                }
            });
```

ChannelHandler :

```
public class ChannelHandler  extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<String> {

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("[+] Channel connected: " + ctx.channel().remoteAddress());
        new ClientHandler(ctx.channel());
    }

    @Override
    public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Channel disconnected: " + ctx.channel().remoteAddress() + " [-]");
        ctx.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String msg) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(ctx.channel().remoteAddress() + ": " + msg);
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Exception caught, closing channel." + cause);
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the client sending any message after connecting successfully? In the channel active(...) method i believe you should remove new channelhandler creation and try.

Comment: Hey yes the client sends a message after any successful connection.

Comment: Can you try by removing new channelhandler creation in chanelActive(...) method? Not sure why it is needed. Can you post the client code as well?

Comment: While sending the data from client, did you include the `Delimiters.lineDelimiter()` (i.e., \r\n) in the data?

Comment: Can you test the server with something as simple as telnet? it shows quickly if the server or the client is atfault

Answer (score 0):

Solved By:
ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter

Instead Of:SimpleChannelInboundHandler